# Compare multiple time series

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I have multiple time series data.

```
c1= c(0.558642328, 
0.567173803, 
0.572518969, 
0.579917556, 
0.592155421, 
0.600239837, 
0.598955071, 
0.608857572, 
0.615442061, 
0.613502347, 
0.618076897, 
0.626769781, 
0.633930194, 
0.645518577, 
0.66773088, 
0.68128165, 
0.695552504, 
0.6992836, 
0.702771866, 
0.700840271, 
0.684032428, 
0.665082645, 
0.646948862, 
0.621813893, 
0.597888613, 
0.577744126, 
0.555984044, 
0.533597678, 
0.523645413, 
0.522041142, 
0.525437844, 
0.53053292, 
0.543152606, 
0.549038792, 
0.555300856, 
0.563411331, 
0.572663951, 
0.584438777, 
0.589476192, 
0.604197562, 
0.61670388, 
0.624161184, 
0.624345171, 
0.629342985, 
0.630379665, 
0.620067096, 
0.597480375, 
0.576228619, 
0.561285031, 
0.543921304, 
0.530826211, 
0.519563568, 
0.514228535, 
0.515202665, 
0.516663855, 
0.525673366, 
0.543545395, 
0.551681638, 
0.558951402, 
0.566816133, 
0.573842585, 
0.578611696, 
0.589180577, 
0.603297615, 
0.624550509, 
0.641310155, 
0.655093217, 
0.668385196, 
0.671600127, 
0.658876967, 
0.641041982, 
0.605081463, 
0.585503519, 
0.556173635, 
0.527428073, 
0.502755737, 
0.482510734, 
0.453295642, 
0.439938772, 
0.428757811, 
0.422361642, 
0.40945864, 
0.399504355, 
0.412688798, 
0.42684828, 
0.456935656, 
0.48355422, 
0.513727218, 
0.541630101, 
0.559122121, 
0.561763656, 
0.572532833, 
0.576761365, 
0.576146233, 
0.580199403, 
0.584954906)


c2 = c(0.548312998, 
0.557590675, 
0.569792616, 
0.57648288, 
0.582519495, 
0.584094632, 
0.583095658, 
0.58734405, 
0.590847301, 
0.588833773, 
0.591280174, 
0.60634923, 
0.614732516, 
0.628865051, 
0.64757216, 
0.666375887, 
0.677957845, 
0.681262505, 
0.684586871, 
0.682824385, 
0.667175573, 
0.648371458, 
0.633537549, 
0.608043456, 
0.581588411, 
0.559924698, 
0.540028617, 
0.517327446, 
0.507012364, 
0.501844284, 
0.503439355, 
0.509529454, 
0.521872091, 
0.526565039, 
0.534752142, 
0.54074347, 
0.548374414, 
0.563411844, 
0.568870294, 
0.58314842, 
0.59602412, 
0.611573255, 
0.617278945, 
0.622240722, 
0.619769347, 
0.610022175, 
0.593835229, 
0.568100679, 
0.551525283, 
0.529572153, 
0.51428445, 
0.499277723, 
0.494636112, 
0.497823489,
0.498831296,
0.504156655,
0.518578172,
0.526088589,
0.537710232,
0.542733413,
0.555014384,
0.561118293,
0.56687597,
0.581570888,
0.604392135,
0.618327677,
0.635660493,
0.651578796,
0.644108343,
0.628193212,
0.608698857,
0.577001792,
0.559129715,
0.535084575,
0.511081594,
0.490507799,
0.470004833,
0.438273591,
0.425731319,
0.414378071,
0.411413676,
0.400676805,
0.396925634,
0.399999064,
0.412862909,
0.431658995,
0.458585095,
0.488017178,
0.509648013,
0.529197955,
0.535413015,
0.543576932,
0.544105291,
0.547104096,
0.54662621,
0.543324244)


c3 = c(0.232481461,
0.234331533,
0.236983097,
0.239418665,
0.251142623,
0.258787839,
0.27416779,
0.288656804,
0.311543879,
0.318174845,
0.322510272,
0.322567761,
0.327798945,
0.328320512,
0.334473217,
0.348781505,
0.361979774,
0.370497525,
0.371140084,
0.364378414,
0.351432962,
0.334426059,
0.311300224,
0.28731017,
0.253390689,
0.225132306,
0.199986064,
0.174223486,
0.164470221,
0.161742944,
0.165116308,
0.171975482,
0.192469646,
0.199604255,
0.217081873,
0.227614346,
0.234985653,
0.249016567,
0.258492273,
0.270134681,
0.284708416,
0.300111979,
0.301602611,
0.299326849,
0.301946108,
0.28775356,
0.265379742,
0.233876735,
0.214674118,
0.186715491,
0.166108309,
0.147216564,
0.145897944,
0.147968549,
0.146944046,
0.162383635,
0.184625961,
0.200818598,
0.215416914,
0.226366764,
0.233739947,
0.237156208,
0.241002475,
0.250965495,
0.268156333,
0.278750855,
0.301519382,
0.319674549,
0.307104857,
0.28811741,
0.264678046,
0.223922733,
0.199140929,
0.177024715,
0.152031524,
0.127592109,
0.111354212,
0.079259231,
0.067813135,
0.06893201,
0.072917068,
0.075522878,
0.070564032,
0.05824402,
0.049086138,
0.050384771,
0.050128536,
0.061492301,
0.086675285,
0.10030736,
0.107977158,
0.119556361,
0.120863232,
0.116997129,
0.119532892,
0.117785394)
```

and the date sequence for the data is:

```
dates = seq(as.Date("2016-09-01"), as.Date("2020-07-30"), by=15) #96 times observation
```

My question is what statistical methods can be applied to evaluate the similarity or differences among the time series? Can we evaluate if trends of the time series are statistically different to each other or not, and at what level? The question could be broad and generic. Appreciate suggestions regarding statistical tests, and possibly line of codes to assess these questions.

To add, the data has strong seasonality component.

I have found some discussions
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19103/how-to-statistically-compare-two-time-series ,
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372086/statistically-evaluate-difference-between-time-series?noredirect=1&lq=1
but could not infer meaningful ideas to what I want to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Chow test is used to test whether two time series data come from the same regression.

> A Chow test is used to test whether the coefficients in two different regression models on different datasets are equal.
>
> This test is typically used in the field of econometrics with time series data to determine if there is a structural break in the data at some point.

Clearly, from the plots the time series seem very similar, with series 3 lower than the other two. There is visual evidence that the lag 1 difference might be the same among all three series.

[image]

The way to perform the test is to put the lag 1 difference in a single vector and specify the separation point. This is done comparing c1 vs c2, c2 vs c3, and c1 vs c3.

```
c1= c(0.558642328, 
      0.567173803, 
      0.572518969, 
      0.579917556, 
      0.592155421, 
      0.600239837, 
      0.598955071, 
      0.608857572, 
      0.615442061, 
      0.613502347, 
      0.618076897, 
      0.626769781, 
      0.633930194, 
      0.645518577, 
      0.66773088, 
      0.68128165, 
      0.695552504, 
      0.6992836, 
      0.702771866, 
      0.700840271, 
      0.684032428, 
      0.665082645, 
      0.646948862, 
      0.621813893, 
      0.597888613, 
      0.577744126, 
      0.555984044, 
      0.533597678, 
      0.523645413, 
      0.522041142, 
      0.525437844, 
      0.53053292, 
      0.543152606, 
      0.549038792, 
      0.555300856, 
      0.563411331, 
      0.572663951, 
      0.584438777, 
      0.589476192, 
      0.604197562, 
      0.61670388, 
      0.624161184, 
      0.624345171, 
      0.629342985, 
      0.630379665, 
      0.620067096, 
      0.597480375, 
      0.576228619, 
      0.561285031, 
      0.543921304, 
      0.530826211, 
      0.519563568, 
      0.514228535, 
      0.515202665, 
      0.516663855, 
      0.525673366, 
      0.543545395, 
      0.551681638, 
      0.558951402, 
      0.566816133, 
      0.573842585, 
      0.578611696, 
      0.589180577, 
      0.603297615, 
      0.624550509, 
      0.641310155, 
      0.655093217, 
      0.668385196, 
      0.671600127, 
      0.658876967, 
      0.641041982, 
      0.605081463, 
      0.585503519, 
      0.556173635, 
      0.527428073, 
      0.502755737, 
      0.482510734, 
      0.453295642, 
      0.439938772, 
      0.428757811, 
      0.422361642, 
      0.40945864, 
      0.399504355, 
      0.412688798, 
      0.42684828, 
      0.456935656, 
      0.48355422, 
      0.513727218, 
      0.541630101, 
      0.559122121, 
      0.561763656, 
      0.572532833, 
      0.576761365, 
      0.576146233, 
      0.580199403, 
      0.584954906)


c2 = c(0.548312998, 
       0.557590675, 
       0.569792616, 
       0.57648288, 
       0.582519495, 
       0.584094632, 
       0.583095658, 
       0.58734405, 
       0.590847301, 
       0.588833773, 
       0.591280174, 
       0.60634923, 
       0.614732516, 
       0.628865051, 
       0.64757216, 
       0.666375887, 
       0.677957845, 
       0.681262505, 
       0.684586871, 
       0.682824385, 
       0.667175573, 
       0.648371458, 
       0.633537549, 
       0.608043456, 
       0.581588411, 
       0.559924698, 
       0.540028617, 
       0.517327446, 
       0.507012364, 
       0.501844284, 
       0.503439355, 
       0.509529454, 
       0.521872091, 
       0.526565039, 
       0.534752142, 
       0.54074347, 
       0.548374414, 
       0.563411844, 
       0.568870294, 
       0.58314842, 
       0.59602412, 
       0.611573255, 
       0.617278945, 
       0.622240722, 
       0.619769347, 
       0.610022175, 
       0.593835229, 
       0.568100679, 
       0.551525283, 
       0.529572153, 
       0.51428445, 
       0.499277723, 
       0.494636112, 
       0.497823489,
       0.498831296,
       0.504156655,
       0.518578172,
       0.526088589,
       0.537710232,
       0.542733413,
       0.555014384,
       0.561118293,
       0.56687597,
       0.581570888,
       0.604392135,
       0.618327677,
       0.635660493,
       0.651578796,
       0.644108343,
       0.628193212,
       0.608698857,
       0.577001792,
       0.559129715,
       0.535084575,
       0.511081594,
       0.490507799,
       0.470004833,
       0.438273591,
       0.425731319,
       0.414378071,
       0.411413676,
       0.400676805,
       0.396925634,
       0.399999064,
       0.412862909,
       0.431658995,
       0.458585095,
       0.488017178,
       0.509648013,
       0.529197955,
       0.535413015,
       0.543576932,
       0.544105291,
       0.547104096,
       0.54662621,
       0.543324244)


c3 = c(0.232481461,
       0.234331533,
       0.236983097,
       0.239418665,
       0.251142623,
       0.258787839,
       0.27416779,
       0.288656804,
       0.311543879,
       0.318174845,
       0.322510272,
       0.322567761,
       0.327798945,
       0.328320512,
       0.334473217,
       0.348781505,
       0.361979774,
       0.370497525,
       0.371140084,
       0.364378414,
       0.351432962,
       0.334426059,
       0.311300224,
       0.28731017,
       0.253390689,
       0.225132306,
       0.199986064,
       0.174223486,
       0.164470221,
       0.161742944,
       0.165116308,
       0.171975482,
       0.192469646,
       0.199604255,
       0.217081873,
       0.227614346,
       0.234985653,
       0.249016567,
       0.258492273,
       0.270134681,
       0.284708416,
       0.300111979,
       0.301602611,
       0.299326849,
       0.301946108,
       0.28775356,
       0.265379742,
       0.233876735,
       0.214674118,
       0.186715491,
       0.166108309,
       0.147216564,
       0.145897944,
       0.147968549,
       0.146944046,
       0.162383635,
       0.184625961,
       0.200818598,
       0.215416914,
       0.226366764,
       0.233739947,
       0.237156208,
       0.241002475,
       0.250965495,
       0.268156333,
       0.278750855,
       0.301519382,
       0.319674549,
       0.307104857,
       0.28811741,
       0.264678046,
       0.223922733,
       0.199140929,
       0.177024715,
       0.152031524,
       0.127592109,
       0.111354212,
       0.079259231,
       0.067813135,
       0.06893201,
       0.072917068,
       0.075522878,
       0.070564032,
       0.05824402,
       0.049086138,
       0.050384771,
       0.050128536,
       0.061492301,
       0.086675285,
       0.10030736,
       0.107977158,
       0.119556361,
       0.120863232,
       0.116997129,
       0.119532892,
       0.117785394) 

plot(ylim=range(c(c1,c2,c3)), c1, type="l", xlab="Time", ylab="")
lines(c2, type="l", col="red")
lines(c3, type="l", col="blue")

#install.packages("strucchange")
library(strucchange)


dat = data.frame(x = 1:190, c12 = c(diff(c1), diff(c2)), 
                 c13=c(diff(c1),diff(c3)),
                 c23=c(diff(c2),diff(c3)))

sctest(dat$c12 ~ dat$x, type="Chow", point=95)
sctest(dat$c13 ~ dat$x, type="Chow", point=95)
sctest(dat$c23 ~ dat$x, type="Chow", point=95)
```

According to the results, all three come from possibly the same regression. Nonetheless c1 appears more similar to c2 than they are to c3.

Output

```
> sctest(dat$c12 ~ dat$x, type="Chow", point=95)

    Chow test

data:  dat$c12 ~ dat$x
F = 0.010695, p-value = 0.9894

> sctest(dat$c13 ~ dat$x, type="Chow", point=95)

    Chow test

data:  dat$c13 ~ dat$x
F = 0.25134, p-value = 0.778

> sctest(dat$c23 ~ dat$x, type="Chow", point=95)

    Chow test

data:  dat$c23 ~ dat$x
F = 0.2534, p-value = 0.7764
```

Comment: Thanks @GoldenGateBridge. How are the results evaluated/interpreted and discussed?

Comment: @kl40 If the pvalue > alpha = 0.05, there is no structural change point at 95, which is where the two time series are appended together. Since the pvalues are all very high, the two data likely come from the same distribution for each pairwise comparison

Comment: thanks, understand it. But how can I say they are statistically different? The concept sounds interesting, but it is a bit difficult for me to understand the science/theory behind the test.